# Eloquent modelo vació al codificar en json

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy utilizando eloquent para extraer datos del modelo de usuario, con las versiones actuales no hay problema, pero estoy usando la version 4.1 porque es la única que soporta el servidor php 5.4. resulta que al hacer:

```
$usuario=Dbuser::all();
json_encode($usuario);
```

la salida muestra {}, Sin embargo si le hago un var_dump($usuario) dice que el modelo trae 5 items. La siguiente prueba que hice.

```
$usuario=Dbuser::all()->toArray();
json_encode($usuario);
```

Esto muestra de forma correcta los resultados, pero no quiero tener que escribir toArray() en todos mis metodos. la ultima prueba que hice fue

```
 $usuario=Dbuser::all();
foreach($usuario as $data){
   var_dump($data);
}
```

Esto daba como resultado cada una de las filas y cada atributo accesible mediante $data->Nombre; ¿será un bug de esta versión?, o debo de cambiar algo en la configuración del Capsule que me devuelva de manera correcta los datos al hacer json_encode.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use app\App;
$capsule = new Capsule;
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' =>App::$dbConnection['type'],
    'host' => App::$dbConnection['host'],
    'database' => App::$dbConnection['db'],
    'username' => App::$dbConnection['user'],
    'password' => App::$dbConnection['pass'],
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => ''
],'website');

$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Este es del dump de Dbuser::all(); Lo mismo por los 5 elementos

```
  object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[25]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => 
        object(models\Dbuser)[18]
          protected 'connection' => string 'website' (length=7)
          protected 'table' => string 'user' (length=4)
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id_user' (length=7)
          public 'timestamps' => boolean false
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'exists' => boolean true
          protected 'softDelete' => boolean false
      1 => 
        object(models\Dbuser)[19]
          protected 'connection' => string 'website' (length=7)
          protected 'table' => string 'user' (length=4)
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id_user' (length=7)
          public 'timestamps' => boolean false
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'exists' => boolean true
          protected 'softDelete' => boolean false
```

Comment: No es cierto lo que dices, PHP 5.4 fue soportado hasta Laravel 5.0. Por favor agrega el dump de `Dbuser::all();`

Comment: @Shaz Probé de la version 4.2 de illuminate/eloquent  en adelante todas generaban conflicto porque en php 5.4 no se soporta la llamada de este tipo Model::class, la cual utilizan las clases de eloquent por lo cual no lo podía implementar. pondré el dump

Comment: @Shaz este es el error de eloquent 4.2 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in

Comment: El error es exactamente acá eloquent/illuminate/support/Traits/Macroable.php  ya que utiliza ::class y esto no es compatible con php 5.4

Comment: La verdad no veo en ninguna parte que haga un llamado así en ese archivo de Laravel 4.2 https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/MacroableTrait.php

Comment: @Shaz Tu hablas de laravel, yo hablo de eloquent, la version de eloquent es la 4.2 la que da error, la de laravel creo que no es la misma, y no se como averiguar cual es.

Comment: ¿Eh? Llevo 3 años usando Laravel y que yo sepa Eloquent forma parte del paquete Illuminate\Database que simplemente forma parte de Laravel. ¿Tienes un enlace al repositorio independiente de Eloquent donde pueda ver dichas versiones?

Comment: @Shaz https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database

Comment: El error que te muestra es del paquete support, no de database, por lo visto estás instalando una versión más reciente que la 5.0 de dicha dependencia https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/5.0/Traits/Macroable.php

Comment: Gracias por contestar hermano, le hice un composer update especificando  el platform en el json y ya funciona bien, probablemente era la version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue actualizar los paquetes con composer, composer update y especificando el platform en el json

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.4.0"
    }
},
```